# How to prevent QTableView from user editing but to change its cells from another thread?

Tags: sql, multithreading, qt, qtableview

I have a windows with `QTableView` which shows SQLite table contents. The user must not change cells, they are read-only for him. But another `QThread`-linked worker will change its cells (it uses another database connection). Which classes can I use for this purpose? `QSqlQueryModel` for GUI thread and `QSqlQuery` for the worker thread?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you set the [`editTriggers`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/qabstractitemview.html#editTriggers-prop) of the view to `QAbstractItemView::NoEditTriggers`

Comment: So, can I use a single QSqlTableModel instead of QSqlQueryModel and QSqlQuery for my purpose if I set `QAbstractItemView::NoEditTriggers`?

Comment: yeah should then  the only changes to the model can come from your code or the query